# Any method to write Ruby without adding "end"?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Ruby is a beatifull language, but with a key word "end" which I hates to write many many times.
Is there any method by which I can write concise code without writing "end" every time?

Comment: Maybe { }, I'm not sure of it.

Comment: You chose the wrong language. Phython is the language for people like you.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: No. That is Ruby's block syntax and can not be used for methods, while loops, or all of the like. Also, I don't think that Ruby's {} can span multiple lines. For that you are supposed to use `do...end`.

Comment: {} can be surely used for more lines, I don't know if can be used for methods, by the way what sawa said is definitely correct: Python is the language you should choose in this case.

Comment: @sawa , Yes, I like Python. Learnt basic Python skills before tring to learn about Python. Just want to make writing other languages may be as concise as Python.

Comment: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5054 has a patch that'd solve all your worries. `ennnnnnd` FTW!

Comment: Voting to re-open as it has objective answers.

Comment: This question is perfectly reasonable! Disregard the close-minded mods. In answer, **yes you can**. There's a Ruby preprocessor/transcompiler that lets you omit the `end` keyword, assuming you indent Python-stylee. It's called [**Endless Ruby**](https://github.com/pasberth/EndlessRuby)

Comment: @ColonelPanic Thanks. That's the language I was looking for.

Comment: Voting to re-open. It's not okay to close a question without commenting. If you think the answer to OP's question is "no it's not possible", post that as an answer.

Comment: There's: https://github.com/michaeledgar/seamless

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, this is partially non-responsive, but originally, `begin ... end` was the paradigm. And by *originally*, I mean languages you or I have never seen; things called funny names like *Algol.* Some languages *(FORTRAN, Basic)* staggered along for years with only single-statement conditionals.

Then C, and later, Java, came along and took over the world. They had **{ .. }.** and that was not bad.

Python and a few others (including a microcode assembler I wrote years before Python was invented) have experimented with *using indent* for block structure. Nice solution but apparently it wasn't all that popular.

All of those *worked* but there were various issues.

Believe it or not, Ruby's syntax design no-doubt involved consideration of *all* these other less-than-perfect dead ends.

My suggestion is: *give it another chance* just the way it is.

Ruby merges the groundbreaking and technically worshipped `Smalltalk` and `Lisp` with the practical and actually useful `Perl.` For whatever reason, Smalltalk and (((Lisp))) haven't succeeded in 30 and 55 years, roughly, and Perl is fading. Ruby is by far the most advanced language ever to become popular.

The future is Ruby (and Python and JavaScript) and people like Ruby for a reason. One of those reasons is the really user-friendly syntax.

Believe me, the alternatives are worse.

Keep trying!

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is the case where indentation would fall short?

Answer (score 8):

You don't actually have to write `end` at all to write Ruby:

```
Foo = Class.new {
  define_method(:bar) {
      puts "I don't recommend this"; \
      return 42 \
    if (:what_is_going_on?)
  }
}

Foo.new.bar # => 42
```

Expect other Rubyists reading your code to wonder what got through your mind, though...

Another possibility without any `end` that replaces all the dreadful `end` with your favorite character:

```
# encoding: utf-8

define_singleton_method(:_){|code|
  eval(code.gsub("◊", "e\156d"))
}

_ <<-EOC
  class Foo
    def bar
      if :what_is_going_on?
        puts "I don't recommend this either"
        return 42
      ◊
    ◊
  ◊
  p Foo.new.bar  # => 42
EOC
```

Or replace `_` with your own parser that generates `end`s according to the indentation!

Comment: Wow, that's amazing!